# Use declare variables with the like operator (variables gets they value by a c# program)

Tags: c#, sql-server

i got this problem where i want to use a declare variables on my procedure, but first the value cant be 0 on int type and i dont know if my code is rigth, and second to read my variable declared

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[lookemp]
@id_emp int,
@nom_emp varchar(100),
@lnom_emp varchar(100),
@l2nom_emp varchar(100),
@id_area int,
@id_supervisor int,
@id_type int
as begin
if @id_emp = 0 (select @id_emp = null)
if @id_area = 0 (select @id_area = null)
if @id_type = 0 (select @id_type = null)
if @id_supervisor = 0 (select @id_supervisor = null)
select distinct * from empleados as e where e.id_emp like '%@id_emp%' and
                                            e.nom_emp like '%@nom_emp%' and
                                            e.lnom_emp like '%@lnom_emp%' and
                                            e.l2nom_emp like '%l2nom_emp%' and
                                            e.id_area like '%@id_area%' and
                                            e.id_supervisor like '%@id_supervisor%' and
                                            e.id_type like '%@id_type%'
return
end
```

this is my c# code

```
emp_adap = new SqlDataAdapter("dbo.lookemp", var.coneccion);
                    emp_adap.SelectCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlCommandBuilder cmdbuild = new SqlCommandBuilder(emp_adap);
                    DataTable emp_table = new DataTable();
                    emp_table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                    emp_adap.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id_emp", get_idemp()));
                    emp_adap.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nom_emp", txtnom.Text));
                    emp_adap.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lnom_emp", txtlnom.Text));
                    emp_adap.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@l2nom_emp", txtl2nom.Text));
                    emp_adap.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id_area", get_idarea()));
                    emp_adap.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id_supervisor", get_idsupervisor()));
                    emp_adap.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id_type", get_idtype()));

                    var.coneccion.Open();
                    emp_adap.Fill(emp_table);
                    emp_bind.DataSource = emp_table;
                    var.coneccion.Close();
```

the methods get_ idarea, get_idemp, get_idtype, get_idsuper return by default a 0

Comment: i tried change the null value on the conditions to ''

Comment: T-SQL variables are not interpolated; to use them with a `LIKE` you need to `... like '%' + @id_emp + '%' ` - Do you really want to use `LIKE` with an `int` ?`

Comment: I would also note that you are using ANDs which require EVERY field to match, and you and using the string `LIKE` function on supposedly numeric columns (IDs) which will implicitly convert the numbers to strings.

Comment: and `set @id_emp = nullif(@id_emp, 0)` is equivalent to `if @id_emp = 0 (select @id_emp = null)`

Comment: for an int you probably need ....like '%' + CAST(@id_emp AS VARCHAR(50)) + '%'....

Comment: @AlexK. you was right, with the like  on an int and the sintaxis thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just got it thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/246342/alex-k and  https://stackoverflow.com/users/203262/shantanu-gupta

now the advance search filter the data no matters wich parameters you give

```
  ALTER procedure [dbo].[lookemp]
@id_emp int,
@nom_emp varchar(100),
@lnom_emp varchar(100),
@l2nom_emp varchar(100),
@id_area int,
@id_supervisor int,
@id_type int
as begin
if @id_emp = 0 (select @id_emp = null)
if @id_area = 0 (select @id_area = null )
if @id_type = 0 (select @id_type = null)
if @id_supervisor = 0 (select @id_supervisor = null)
if @nom_emp = '' (select @nom_emp = null)
if @lnom_emp = '' (select @lnom_emp = null)
if @l2nom_emp = '' (select @l2nom_emp = null)
select distinct * from empleados as e where 
                                            (
                                            (@id_emp is null or e.id_emp = @id_emp)and
                                            (@nom_emp is null or e.nom_emp like '%'+@nom_emp+'%') and
                                            (@lnom_emp is null or e.lnom_emp like @lnom_emp+'%') and
                                            (@l2nom_emp is null or e.l2nom_emp like @l2nom_emp+'%') and
                                            (@id_area is null or e.id_area = @id_area) and
                                            (@id_supervisor is null or e.id_supervisor = @id_supervisor) and
                                            (@id_type is null or e.id_type = @id_type)  
                                            )
return
end
```